# Is there a way to import Amazon-bought Genesis games into the Sega Genesis Classics Hub?

Tags: steam, sega-genesis-classics

The "3D bedroom" interface was recently released on Steam for the Sega Genesis Classics game series.  It works fine for the 3 Genesis games I got through Steam, but the 40+ titles I bought from Amazon do not show up.

In the old interface (which is still usable, but not nearly as much fun), I was able to combine my Steam-bought and Amazon-bought games by copying the game files from both stores into a single folder.  Is there a similar workaround for the new Hub interface?